# The correct link(url) to add a product in my cart in new versions of woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need the link that can make succesful addtion of a product in my cart so i can then use that link for the users to directly go to checkout page and skip the cart page and the procuct page .(ill anchor it as a button "buy now" or something like this)
i dont want to show the product pages and the cart page, i want only the checkout page.
On the latest versions of woocommerce this link worked: 
"domain.com/checkout-page/?product_id=(the number)&quantity=1"
then i used this plugin for the skipping of the card page:
"Yoshop Direct Checkout"
and it worked before, but now with the new versions of woocommerce it seems to not work properly
there is a new better plugin for skipping cart ("WooCommerce Direct Checkout")
and when i try to use the above custom link for adding a product to the cart  - it just dont work.
i have to moove back to the buggy shitty "Yoshop Direct Checkout" - which is supper bad for this new versions of woocommerce.
so i need some kind of solution for the problem, also any workaround will work too.
i just need to make it work stable.
Please help me .
ive tried everything and nothing seems to work properly :(.
i am missing something i guess.
thanks one more time for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this js function for add product in cart automatically using product ID and after successfull redirect on checkout page and skip cart page.

```
function addToCart(p_id, customqty) {
    jQuery.get('domain.com/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id + '&quantity=' + customqty, function (response) {
       window.location.href = 'domain.com/checkout-page/';
    });
}
```

Comment: i think you didnt understand what my goal is .
So i need to have a custom links that can go directly into my checkout page, but for different products.
this code above seems to be for 1 product id only, i need different links.

i saw how they do it in one another plugin they use this html code:
"
{"
 <form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="10989"><button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Direct Checkout</button></form> " }
"
so how to implement this into a single url link?

Answer (score 0):

place the below code in your theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_user_to_checkout');

function redirect_user_to_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

With this code your add to cart button will take your user to checkout page.